# How to concat a string by looping through for loop in ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I tried to concat a string by looping through an array. But the string doesnt concat, it returns an empty String as declared initially. What is the right way to loop through?

```
<% var a; %>

<% for(var i=0; i<data.categories; i++)  {  %>
             <tr>

                <td><%= data.categories[i].name %></td>
                 <%  a = a + data.categories[i].name;  %>
                <%  }  %>
             </tr>
 <%  }  %>

 <p> <%= a %> </p>
```

Categories Array Content - Food, Drinks, Shopping...

Expected Output:

```
a = Food, Drinks, Shopping...
```

Comment: Please add an example of the expected output

Comment: @DanielR Edited